# Trying to delete local App data, made to work with any computer

Tags: windows, powershell, google-chrome, caching, browser-cache

Made a powershell script to go into AppData\Default\Cache directory and clear it, and it works fine for the system I made it for. However this will be used with hundreds of different computers and I need some way to make the directory work with all of them.

I've tried using:

```
cd %AppData%

$pop = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell

$num = $pop.Popup("This will close *confidential*. Are you sure?",0,"Clear Cache",0x1)

if ($num -eq 1) 
{
  $c = get-process -name "chrome" |stop-process -force ;
  remove-item 'C:\Users\RegisterA\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache' -recurse -force ;
  start-process -filepath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
} 

else {exit}
```

So as you can see this code is made for RegisterA User, but some computers will have RegisterB, RegB, StationA, etc. I need to find a way to make this work on all systems without making employees have to type in current host name.

Comment: the way to access envirnoment variables in PoSh is with `$env:EnvVarName`. something like `$env:USERNAME` to get the current user, or `$env:APPDATA` to get the roaming profile of the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve that path of the local AppData folder from the `LocalAppData` environment variable:

```
if ($num -eq 1) 
{
  $c = get-process -name "chrome" |stop-process -force ;
  remove-item "$env:LocalAppData\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache" -recurse -force ;
  start-process -filepath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
}
```

`$env:LocalAppData` will automatically be replaced by the path to the current user's local app data folder. It's important that you use double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`), otherwise the path will **not** be replaced.

I would also recommend replacing `C:\Program Files (x86)` with `$env:ProgramFiles(x86)` in the same way, since some users may have this folder at a different location.